# Destructuring object when setting property name and key dynamically

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm having a hard time sorting out how make the linter happy by destructuring when dynamically setting an object property and key.

How would I destructure this?

```
const myobj = { foo: 'bar' };
const key = 'foo';
const val = 'baz';

// This is the problem line
myobj[key] = val;
```

:: I cannot delete and repost so I'm appending to the question here ::

All I want to do is this: `myobj.foo = 'baz'` but `foo` is also a variable.

The linter setup on this project tells me to destructure when I try `myobj[key] = val;`

Comment: That line isn't really valid JS in the first place. Please show what you really want to do.

Comment: Please post the exact code you use and the exact error/warning message of the linter.

Comment: um `const myobj = { [key]: val }`

Comment: @epascarello That's not destructuring though. It's really just unclear what the OP is looking for.

Comment: I agree with @Bergi, your code has nothing to do with destructuring.  What are you trying to destructure?

Comment: @Coder please explain what your actual goal is with the line `const myobj[key] = val;` . What would you like to change about the state of your program at that line?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion but @epascarello understood what I required. I was just trying to get the linter to stop complaining that I needed to destructure the way I was assigning the last value.

Comment: "*The linter setup on this project tells me to destructure when I try `myobj[key] = val;`*" - I really doubt that. Please post the linter setup, and at least the exact linter message. There is no destructuring syntax for assigning a variable to a property. (There would be if your code was the other way round, like `val = myobj[key];`)

Answer (score 0):

The bit of code you posted is not really relevant to destructuring .

```js
const myobj = { foo: 'bar' };
const key = 'foo';
const val = 'bar 2';

// This is the problem line
myobj[key] = val;
console.log(myobj);
```

Destructuring would be more like this:

```js
const myobj = { foo: 'bar' };
const {foo} = myobj;
console.log(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const myobj[key] = val;
           ^^^^^
```

You are trying to declare a property, which is not possible.

A simple assingment without `const` should work.

```
myobj[key] = val;
```